# Rails Fragment caching vs. eager loading in 2024

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, eager-loading

I'm working on a mature Rails app to speed up our main index page, which was taking 5-6 seconds to render. I recently noticed some N+1s that hadn't been picked up by Bullet, so I implemented the new `strict_loading` method on the query, and included associations accordingly. It now does quite a bit of eager loading:

```rb
[{ thumb_image: [:image_votes, :license, :projects, :user] }
 :location, :name,
 { titles: :votes },
 :projects, :logs, :user]
```

This helped page load time a bit. But what improved it the most is when I started implementing fragment caching on the partials of each object. That took load time down to 3-4 seconds. Something like this:

```
Views: 62.4ms | ActiveRecord: 3356.4ms | Allocations: 592258
```

But the page is still slow. The objects being queried are not only heavy with associations, but objects are also added or updated pretty constantly. And users visit pretty often.

So we cannot cache the index query, to keep the page fresh, even though most visitors are getting 90% cache hits. And we now have a situation where the query is >95% of the average render time of the page. That's because it's eager-loading all those objects and associations, even though it doesn't need 90% of them.

So i'm reconsidering the eager-loading. What I imagine would be better is a light query to get the latest object id's first, and then check `fragment_exist?` on each object partial cache key. Then, whatever's missing, **batch** load the associations for all objects where the cache doesn't exist yet. Something like this:

```rb
objects = Object.where(id: ids.reject { |id| fragment_exist?(cache_key_for_obj_id) }).
          includes(blah blah blah)
```

The question is the cache key. I've checked out old Q&A's on SO about this, but they assume manual cache keys, manually invalidated. With the "newer" automatically generated digests on cache fragment keys in Rails 5 (i'm on Rails 7):

- it doesn't seem like the controller can *know* the cache key, which is generated in the view template
- if I `skip_digest` when generating the cache key, seems like i'd have to manually expire the cache - no thank you, that seems too brittle

What's the way to go, here? Can I somehow check `fragment_exist?` from the controller, including the proper digest, or should I revert to lazy-loading the associations?

If lazy loading, should I call a method to eager load them (per object) from the object partial template itself? That is not only not batching them together, but seems like a serious breach of concerns between the template and the controller. But the partial template seems like the only place that deals with each object separately.

As a [previous questioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180041/fragment-caching-and-eager-loading-how-to-get-the-best-of-both-worlds) put it, "it seems that fragment caching and eager loading are somewhat at odds with each other".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a middleground called batch loading. Eager loading only happens when cache is invalidated, it is a bit of a set up though:

*https://github.com/exAspArk/batch-loader*

```bash
$ bundle add batch-loader
```

```rb
# app/models/post.rb

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  def user_lazy
    # i'm not even gonna try to explain this, you'll have to really read the readme
    BatchLoader.for(user_id).batch do |user_ids, loader|
      User.where(id: user_ids).each { |user| loader.call(user.id, user) }
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # this one is for example purposes, there is a middleware for this
    BatchLoader::Executor.clear_current

    @posts = Post.all
    # no db query for users is executed yet
    @users = @posts.each_with_object({}) do |post, h|
      h[post] = post.user_lazy
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/views/posts/index.html.erb

# collection cache also works, this is just to see it easier in the log
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% cache post do %>
    <%= render post %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

```rb
# app/views/posts/_post.html.erb

<%= tag.div id: dom_id(post) do %>
  # when any of the `cache post` is invalidated, this line will execute
  # and eager load all of the users. when all posts are cached there is
  # no eager loading of users
  <%= @users[post] %>
<% end %>
```

On the first load posts are loaded and users are eager loaded and posts are cached, second visit only posts are needed:

```
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  ↳ app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:10:in `each_with_object'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Read fragment views/posts/index:54ef1a9698061f894cb00c459440f8a6/posts/2-20240122190140985467 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/posts/index:54ef1a9698061f894cb00c459440f8a6/posts/3-20240122185810608401 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/posts/index:54ef1a9698061f894cb00c459440f8a6/posts/4-20240122185810608401 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/posts/index:54ef1a9698061f894cb00c459440f8a6/posts/5-20240122185810608401 (0.1ms)
```

If one cache is invalidated `Post.first.touch`, users get eager loaded again:

```
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  ↳ app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:10:in `each_with_object'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Read fragment views/posts/index:1687a2170041b25d00fcb7bd15638f9e/posts/2-20240122192532103648 (0.2ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" IN (?, ?, ?) OR "users"."id" IS NULL)  [["id", 17], ["id", 19], ["id", 55]]
  ↳ app/models/post.rb:6:in `block in user_lazy'
  Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (Duration: 2.7ms | Allocations: 2761)
Write fragment views/posts/index:1687a2170041b25d00fcb7bd15638f9e/posts/2-20240122192532103648 (0.2ms)
Read fragment views/posts/index:1687a2170041b25d00fcb7bd15638f9e/posts/3-20240122185810608401 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/posts/index:1687a2170041b25d00fcb7bd15638f9e/posts/4-20240122185810608401 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/posts/index:1687a2170041b25d00fcb7bd15638f9e/posts/5-20240122185810608401 (0.1ms)
```

**Update**

Best I could come up with is to check for cache existence from a template:

```rb
<%
  @users = @posts.each_with_object({}) do |post, h|
    unless controller.fragment_exist?(cache_fragment_name(post))
      h[post] = post.user_lazy
    end
  end
%>
```

This way you only eager load when cache is expired and only eager load the users that you need. You'll have to take into account that cache key lookup takes time and now you're doing it twice.

Technically, it can be done from controller:

```rb
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    BatchLoader::Executor.clear_current
    @posts = Post.all

    template    = lookup_context.find(action_name, lookup_context.prefixes)
    digest_path = helpers.digest_path_from_template(template)

    @users = @posts.each_with_object({}) do |post, h|
      unless fragment_exist?([digest_path, post])
        h[post] = post.user_lazy
      end
    end
  end

  # or like this
  def index
    BatchLoader::Executor.clear_current
    @posts = Post.all

    @current_template = lookup_context.find(action_name, lookup_context.prefixes) 

    @users = @posts.each_with_object({}) do |post, h|
      unless fragment_exist?(helpers.cache_fragment_name(post))
        h[post] = post.user_lazy
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sheesh this is brilliant, thank you. Seems like exactly the thing, need to read up on it; will report back when tested. I encountered this gem while starting to build out a GraphQL API for the very same site a couple years ago. (bailed because I had no help to build it... and never got to the point of understanding how BatchLoader works.)

Comment: For each partial in my `Posts` index, I either need all of the associations or, if the partial is cached, none of them. In my example above, I imagine my `thumb_image_lazy` method can eager-load its sub-associations `[:image_votes, :license, :projects, :user]`. If i need to load a `thumb_image`, i need to load all that stuff. Then there's also `:location, :name, :projects, :logs, :user, { titles: :votes }`. Looks like, the way BatchLoader is set up, I need to write an `#{association}_lazy` method for each of those associations, in the `Post` model. Do I have that right?

Comment: Another thought: reading your answer carefully, the `users` are either **all** loaded (if one partial cache is missed!) or none. But our index cache hit is almost never 100%, because posts are added too frequently. Cached partials are usually in the 75%-90% range, according to the logs. But if BatchLoader loads all associations if even one partial needs stuff, this won't help us much.

Comment: @nimmolo yes, you'll need to create a batch for each association that way. all users are loaded, it's why it's only a middleground solution. if you want to check for the existence of the cache key and then only batch the once that are missing you can do `<% @posts.map {|post| controller.fragment_exist?(cache_fragment_name(post)) } %>` i've only managed to do this from a template, because you need a template instance to calculate the template digest that is part of the key (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.3/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/cache_helper.rb#L248)

Comment: Thanks. Yea, i recognize that's a catch-22, we can't access the template digest from the controller where we'd ideally want to be doing the query. Would Bruno's suggestion work, to use a custom key like `cache(["post", post.id, post.updated_at]) do`, making the key both accessible in the controller and auto-invalidated because `updated_at` becomes part of the key?

Comment: Just noticed your updated answer, sorry for missing that earlier. Will try that. One side question, to calibrate my expectations - Admittedly my description is incomplete, but does it seem normal for a Rails query with associations as described above, where the main post table has a half million objects, for the query to take 3 to 4 seconds? The site is just incredibly slow, I don't remember encountering such a slow site elsewhere. Maybe that's worth a separate question.

Comment: Within `each_with_object`, in your updated template block, do i need to call each of the rest of the `#{associations}_lazy` as well as  `user_lazy`, separately, on the post? Can I chain them, like `post.user_lazy.title_lazy.location_lazy.name_lazy...`? I don't find anything about that in the docs.

Comment: @nimmolo I don't think you can chain the method calls, because as soon as you start accessing the batch instance (returned by `user_lazy`) it triggers the eager loading, you could maybe do something inside `BatchLoader` block. but also if you're checking for cache keys in advance maybe you could avoid batch-loader entirely. 3-4 seconds could maybe be improved, this probably is a separate question for SQL folks, maybe you're missing some needed indexes.

Comment: @nimmolo "Would Bruno's suggestion work" - yes, but the cache will not be invalidated when the template changes. see update if you want to do it from controller.

Comment: Got it. I've seen examples where people "version" their manual cache keys, i guess that would be necessary for template updates in that case. Something like `cache(["v1", "post", post.id, post.updated_at]) do`

Comment: Finally testing out your "Technically, it can be done from the controller:" example. Whew, now that's what I needed. Thank you for all the follow-ups. I will mark this as accepted and maybe also post an answer showing my final setup and why, because i think it might be helpful to others. This seems to me a standard example that should be documented: "heavy eager loads that may be unnecessary with caching."

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using this cache pattern: [Rails caching: russian doll](https://patrickkarsh.medium.com/rails-caching-patterns-russian-doll-caching-dca569d04fe0)

Also you will need to set up your own cache keys. You can use the updated_at attribute as part of it in order to ensure that the object didn't change.

Please give further information about the problem you're dealing with.

Comment: Thank you Bruno, i never thought of using `updated_at` as part of the key. You are recommending also to `skip_digest`, right? (I don't believe the Russian doll pattern will help in this case, because the partial is fairly simple, the associations are loaded to calculate small bits of content in the partial, but all of the associations change `updated_at` of the main object)

Comment: @nimmolo I have used updated_at as part of the key before in order to just cache the object only if it not change. Is also important what and where you're caching. Because you can cache partials, of course, but also objects, so you can consider a server caching of the object and it relationships, and just render the partial without loading the whole records from the DB, but the cache ones.